# The project is not compiled due to moxy

Tags: android, moxy

My project does not compile:

```
e: error: Moxy compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: couldn't make a guess for ru.Example.drafts.reducer.ReduceView$$State)
```

my dependences:

```
implementation 'com.github.moxy-community:moxy:1.0.13'
kapt 'com.github.moxy-community:moxy-compiler:1.0.13'
implementation 'com.github.moxy-community:moxy-androidx:1.0.13'
implementation 'com.github.moxy-community:moxy-material:1.0.13'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the answer https://github.com/moxy-community/Moxy/issues/50. Package names should be all lower case. My package ru.Example.drafts